# Question regarding OAuth2 flows to provide when providing a public API with user-based access

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a question regarding OAuth2 flows. We provide a public API that registered users can use to access our services. A client of ours wants to use the Client Credentials Flow to retrieve an Access Token, requesting ClientId and ClientSecret from me. I am confused as this is in my opinion not the proper way to authorize users but confidential clients which our client is not in my opinion. Do I miss anything? Is there a way to use the Client Credentials Flow only for a defined user in our system. Thanks in advance!

I can only use Client Credentials Flow for our whole application, and not user-based if i tried everything correctly.